# SSH port blocked EC2

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, amazon-ec2, firewall

I had installed Tomcat on my EC2 instance . However i was unable to access it using my public IP:8080 . So I followed the instructions mentioned in the post

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21966082/cannot-access-tomcat-instance-installed-in-ec2

and ran the commands

```
sudo ufw enable
sudo ufw allow 8080
```

After doing this i was able to access my Tomcat instance using Mind Term... However when i try to access my EC2 instance using . I get the following error

```
Error connecting to 54.69.40.85, reason:
 -> Connection timed out: no further information
```

ooks like the firewall is blocking port 22... Any help on how to fix this problem

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable port 22 inbound in the ec2 security group you setup for that instance.